# Clustering groups of data with Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, python

I want to cluster objects. There are two attributes (one categorial and one numerical). They should be clustered after the numerical attribut. But observations with the same categorical value should be grouped in the same cluster, no matter of the numerical attribut. I tried with k-prototypes in python and a change in the gamma value, but ist doesn't worked like I wanted to. I think the problem is that some of the objects with the same categorical value are too different in the numerical values, so k-prototype change them to another cluster which better fits to the numerical value of the object. Is there another possibility? Better algorithm? Maybe to change the pyhon algorithm code and add a restriction that all objects with the same categorical value must belong to the same cluster?
Or is there any other Machine-Learning algorithm which can cluster groups of objects?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: How would this be different from doing a separate clustering (by numeric value only) for each category?

Comment: @Wayne Good question, maybe OP meant that observations with the same category should be more likely to be in the same cluster, and not that they should definitely be. I hope so.

Comment: All objects with the same categorical value should definitely be in the same cluster. So at the end for example one cluster contains all objects with categorical value x, y and z, and another cluster all objects from category a,b and so on

Comment: @n149i12 This just got a lot more complicated. You cannot enforce such a rule in most algorithms, but there may be some method which could allow this. But more importantly, why do you want to do this?

Comment: The clusters should be used for scheduling. user2974951, so you do also not see any way to implement this in a common Machine Learning algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You need a model which can deal with mixed data types, a lot of clustering algorithms deal only with numerical data, for ex. k-means. Or you could try transforming the categories into dummy variables.

I would suggest looking into various metrics which can be used with such data, for ex. Gower distance. Once you have this you can use hierarchical clustering on it, this will take into account the categories.

Answer (score 0):

Don't treat clustering as a black box. You *need* to understand it to use it right.

Methods such as k-means usually come with some objective. If you require all points with the same category to be in the same cluster, consider what this means for the objective function!

Usually, if you study the math, you'll then quickly notice that you should *first* reduce your data to unique categories, then cluster the smaller data set.

For hierarchical clustering: simply always merge all points with the same label first! Once there are no such pairs remaining, continue with merging groups.

For k-means: merge all points with the same label into a group, represented by: 1. the weight, 2. the center, 3. the variance. Then perform a weighted version of k-means, and also consider the variance change when assigning groups of points (single points would have variance 0 obviously, so this is not necessary in regular k-means).

You won't find a library for this, so you better write the code yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I first merge all points with the same label to cluster in a smaller data set, what will happen with the numerical values of all the objects with the same label? I can not just take the average.

Comment: See above. Hierarchical clustering specifies how to more then; in kmeans you'll need to use mean, weight and variance.